# List out the Confident Interval have actual means of 10

Tags: r, confidence-interval

I have a table of Confident Interval as the picture below, the questions asking for how many the Interval contains the actual mean of 10 and list them out.

I only know how to count how many

```
Inside <- 0
for (i in 1:100)
{
if ((CIs[i,1]<10) & ( 10 < CIs[i,2]))
 {
 Inside <- Inside+1
 }
 else {}
}
Inside
```

Could you help me list them out as a matrix? Thank you!

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
subset(CIs, lcl > 10 & ucl < 10)
```

this should list all rows with lcl larger than 10 and ucl smaller than 10. You would need to rplace "CIs" with the name of your data.frame.

Counting can be much easier then with:

```
nrow(subset(CIs, lcl > 10 & ucl < 10))
```

Answer (score 0):

Not clear what tou want. Here is a possibility.

```
# simulates a 'CIs' matrix
set.seed(666)
lwr <- rpois(20, 5)
upr <- lwr + rpois(20, 5)
CIs <- cbind(lwr = lwr, upr = upr)

# find intervals containing 10
contains <- apply(CIs, 1, function(lu) lu[1] < 10 && lu[2] > 10)

cbind(CIs, good = contains)
#       lwr upr good
#  [1,]   7  17    1
#  [2,]   3   8    0
#  [3,]  10  11    0
#  [4,]   3   6    0
#  [5,]   4  11    1
#  [6,]   6  10    0
#  [7,]  10  12    0
#  [8,]   5  10    0
#  [9,]   1   6    0
# [10,]   3  10    0
# [11,]   7  12    1
# [12,]   1   5    0
# [13,]   2   9    0
# [14,]   3   8    0
# [15,]   3   9    0
# [16,]   7  12    1
# [17,]   1   5    0
# [18,]   8  16    1
# [19,]   5  12    1
# [20,]   5  10    0
```